How to Prevent My Python Script from Closing Immediately After Running on Windows?
I'm just starting out with Python on my Windows computer. I wrote a simple script to print "Hello, World!" like this:
print("Hello, World!")

When I double-click the .py file to run it, a command prompt window briefly appears and then closes right away. I can't see the "Hello, World!" message.
How can I make the window stay open after the script finishes so I can read the output?
Thanks in advance!

Run Python script from a command line shell like CMD or PowerShell.

Assuming you have the correct file association (i.e., double-click a file with .py extension runs python) then your script has executed normally then ended. What were you hoping it would do apart from open a terminal, emit "Hello, World!", then close the terminal?

you can use input function
print("Hello, World!")
input("Press Enter to exit...")


Add this line at end of any script
input("Press any Key")
or use time module
import time
// Your code
time.sleep(10)

there will be an delay for the next line to execute, so for 10 seconds your screen will wait and then close.
